# How to insert records from other tables to a table with more columns in sas

Tags: sas

I have two sas tables, A and B, A has two columns (i.e., columna columnb) and table B has four columns (i.e., columna columnb columnc columnd ), I wish to insert records from table A to table B, I tried the following, but it shows me errors:

```
PROC SQL;
  insert into B
   select *, columnc='a', columnd='b' from A;
QUIT;
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: You cannot compare the string 'a' to the variable columnc if columnc does not exist in table A.

Comment: @Tom OP is not trying to compare, I don't think; OP is trying to insert 'a' into `columnc` and 'b' into `columnd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want to leave the extra columns empty then don't include them in the insert. It is much easier to just use SAS code instead of SQL code.

```
proc append base=b data=a force nowarn;
run;
```

For the SQL Insert statement you need to specify which columns in the target table you are writing into, otherwise it assumes you will specify values for all of them.

```
insert into B (columna,columnb)
  select columna,columnb
  from A 
;
```

If instead you want to fill the extra columns with constants then include the constants in the SELECT list.

```
insert into B (columna,columnb,columnc,columnd)
  select columna,columnb,'a','b'
  from A 
;
```

If you are positive that you are providing the values in the right order then you can leave the column names off of the target table specification.

```
insert into B 
  select *,'a','b'
  from A 
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify the variable name that way; in fact, you can't specify the variable at all using `insert into`. See this example:

```
proc sql;
  create table class like sashelp.class;
  alter table class 
    add rownum numeric;
  alter table class
    add othcol numeric;
  insert into class
    select *, 1 as othcol, monotonic() as rownum from sashelp.class;
quit;
```

Here I use `as` to specify the column name, but notice that it doesn't actually work: it puts `1` in the `rownum` column, and the `monotonic()` value in `othcol`, since they're in that order on the table.